# git: remove single commit from the master branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I accidentally put some changes (commit C) to `master` instead of branch. Later I created other branches basing on this changes (`branch1` and `branch2`). Now I'd like to remove changes introduced by commit `C` from all the branches (and move it to `branch-C`). Is it possible?

Current situation:

```
A - B - C - D - - L - M - L - M master  
            |     \                     
            |       - N - O - P branch2                           
            \               
             - E - F - G        branch1
```

Desidered situation:

```
         - C                    branch-C 
        /
    A - B - D - - L - M - L - M master  
            |     \                     
            |       - N - O - P branch2                           
            \               
             - E - F - G        branch1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebase each branch, since every commit references the entire chain of parent commits via the hash.

You can do something like

```
for br in master branch1 branch2
do
  git rebase --onto B C "$br" 
done

git branch branch-C C
```

The loop as written will work seamlessly only if there are no conflicts. In general I'd recommend executing it by hand.

Also, if you're doing it by hand, you can optimize a bit. E.g.

```
git rebase --onto B D master
git rebase --onto Dnew D branch1
git rebase --onto Lnew L branch2
```

where `Dnew` and `Lnew` are the rebased versions of `D` and `L` respectively.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it; please test it on a copy of your repo first.

Comment: Finally I've fetched a clean repository from upstream and then cherry-picked commit that I wanted t use. Anyways -- thanks for help.