# How can I remove an old Git commit from master and turn it into its own branch?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, visual-studio-2022

There is a single commit `C` in my `master` branch history that we have decided needs more work.   It is not the latest commit.  There have been 10+ commits since then.  Fortunately, none of the subsequent commits touched any of the files changed by `C`.

I want to remove this commit from the master branch and simultaneously create a new branch `test-c` from the changes in `C`.  This way, more work can be done on it and then later on it can be merged into `master`.

So I want to go from this:

```
---A---B---C---D---E (master)
```

to this

```
---A---B---D---E (master)
                \
                 '---C (test-c)
```

or even just to this would be fine (I can merge later)

```
---A---B---D---E (master)
        \
         '---C (test-c)
```

The [only relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796853/git-remove-single-commit-from-the-master-branch) I could find on this makes it sound as if I need to either write a script or manually rebase each subsequent  master commit (after `C`) on the previous one.  I am dreading that.  But that answer is 9 years old so I have hope there is a better way.

Is there an easier way to do this in Visual Studio 2022 (or Tortoise Git, which I also use)?  I looked at what VS gave me when I right clicked on this commit in the `master` branch history. I see the following options

[image]

Is any of these what I want?  Or must I do all that rebasing?  If the latter is the case, I'd just as soon add a reverse-commit to master, then create a branch with the changes and let the history look cluttered)

Comment: Your linked answer talks about different dependent branches, your question only shows a single branch. That's why the linked answer is more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert the commit (leaving it in the history), create a new branch and then cherry-pick the original commit. Rewriting published history has a lot of problems, therefore I suggest to revert the changes of the commit.

Cherry-picking is required because otherwise the reverted changes will not be merged again.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git revert bad-commit`
3. `git checkout -b more-work`
4. `git cherry-pick bad-commit`
5. Work on the new branch and eventually merge back

---

If you really need to get rid of the original commit (removing it from the history, not just undoing its changes), you can use an (interactive) rebase. Interactive:

1. `git branch more-work bad-commit`
2. `git rebase -i bad-commit^ master`
3. Change the line with bad commit from `pick` to `drop` (or delete it altogether`
4. Save and exit the file

Non-interactive:

1. `git branch more-work bad-commit`
2. `git rebase --onto bad-commit^ bad-commit master`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
git rebase -i C~
# in the list of revisions, take the first line (C) and move it to be the last line. Save / exit
```

rebase should run and now the branch should be `A <- B <- D <- E <- C` with `master` pointing to `C` (well, `C'`, actually. It's not really the original C revision).

As usual in this cases, consider that you are **rewriting history of the branch** and if this branch has already been shared (other people are already working *on top* of it), then trying to pull this off is perfectly possible but painful so that other people start using the newly rebased branch.